# Create An Admin Order Error 500

Tags: admin, orders

I've got a big issue,

I cant create orders via the admin area, i click create order and it goes straight to a HTTP ERROR 500 page

My accounts.php file is exactly how it should be.

Comment: `accounts.php`???? Are taking about magento?

Comment: yep, magento 2.2.8

Comment: it only happens from within the admin panel when you click create order

Comment: "Create New Order" sorry and then says  currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Go to `app/bootstrap.php` and  uncomment `ini_set('display_errors', 1)`  and see what  error showing

Comment: Please check your system.log and exception.log then past error our here so, we will help you.